# I am trying to use "Android Studio Iguana RC 2" some auto competion is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Have some issue with Hedgehog when it randomly freezes so I am trying to use Iguana and there auto competion dont want to offer me to auto compelete classes from my own modules. I cant find any bug report for this so I am puzzled how can be I alone to have this? Its already release candidate 2. Anyone have some issues ? Is there some workaround?

Of course I tried "Invalidate caches". I always just go back to Hedgehog that works good sometimes for hours or a day then it just freezez again also during autio completion popup I just have to kill and restart.

This all is on mac Apple if that matters.